# In arm64 assembly, what does "adrp x0, idmap_pg_dir;" instruction mean?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, arm64

A question on arm64 assembly language.
For example in linux 5.9.15 source code, in arch/arm64/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S (linker script), there is a line `idmap_pg_dir = .;`. so idmap_pg_dir is an address.  Now, in arch/arm64/kernel/head.S, there is a line `adrp    x0, idmap_pg_dir`. Does this mean

```
1) x0 = PC + idmap_pg_dir  or  
2) x0 = idmap_pg_dir  ?
```

I thought when we do `adrp x0, addr1`, usually `addr1` is a PC-relative address offset and x0 becomes `PC + addr`. But the linker script seems to say `idmap_pg_dir` is just an absolute address. (is it not?)  So I'm confused. Please someone correct me.

Comment: It will become a PC relative address but the linker calculates the offset such that it eventually gives the correct result, so `x0 = idmap_pg_dir ` (assuming it's page aligned).  If you do `objdump -dr` on `head.o` you should see the relocation type.

Comment: You mean the compiler/linker generates position independent code(PIC), so even the variable address in the linker script is converted to PC-relative values and the final result is correct? It seems so. (you can make an answer and I can choose it). The objdump -dr thing I'll check tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ARMv8 architecture reference manual, in ADRP instruction section, it says,

> Is the program label whose 4KB page address is to be
> calculated. Its offset from the page address of this instruction, in
> the range +/-4GB, is encoded as "immhi:immlo" times 4096.

So the compiler 'calculates' the 'offset' to the 'label'. So the 'offset' from current instrction is used instead of the absolute address of the label.

Comment: In effect, it's `x0 = pc + (idmap_pg_dir - .)`.